# How to zip files in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write this code to create a zip file from my images

```
        $path = '/path/to/file/icon1.png';
        $path2 = '/path/to/file/icon2.png';
        $this->zip->read_file($path);
        $this->zip->read_file($path2);
        $this->zip->archive('/root/myarchive.zip');
```

Now i want to add a directory using `add_dir` for example `Image` and then add `$path` and `$path2` to this folder and then create an archive (by default CI save these images to the root of zip file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> **$this->zip->add_dir()**
>
> ---
>
> Permits you to add a directory. Usually this function is unnecessary since you can place your data into folders when using $this->zip->add_data(), but if you would like to create an empty folder you can do so. Example:

```
$this->zip->add_dir('myfolder'); // Creates a folder called "myfolder"
```

Simply you can prepend the directory name to the paths:

```
$path = '/path/to/file/icon1.png';
$this->zip->add_data('myfolder/' . $path, file_get_contents($path));
```

If you want to use `$this->zip->read_file()` and maintain the directory structure of the file,  pass TRUE (boolean) in the second parameter. - Says DOCs

```
$path = '/path/to/photo.jpg';
$this->zip->read_file($path, TRUE);
```

> In the above example, photo.jpg will be placed inside two folders: path/to/

Comment: In what moment did you add the whole folder into the zip and created it?